# MFCC features for word boundary detection

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language

How can the MFCC features extracted from a speech signal be used to perform word/sentence boundary detection?

Answer (score 0):

You may check pieces of literature related to speech activity detection (SAD). Usually, you do not need MFCCs for boundary detection; only speech energies are sufficient. However, in noisy cases, the MFCCs are a good choice. You need a good amount of labeled data to train your binary classifier for speech and non-speech detection. Finally, you can detect the speech end-points from the SAD labels.